# Show volume peak of default device output

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I got code that shows volume peak of selected device. How can i make it to show volume peak without selecting device from ComboBox1?

Here`s my code:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(devices.ToArray());   
        }

        private NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader wave = null;
        private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output = null;

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                var device = (MMDevice) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
                progressBar1.Value = (int)(Math.Round(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100));
        }



}
```

Comment: ComboBox may have multiple devices. Do you want to show volume peak for first device if no device is selected?

Comment: I want to show volume peak for default device without selecting it in combobox.

Comment: Do you have object of default device? Is it already available in combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something like this.

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MMDevice device = null;

    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        device = (MMDevice)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    else
        device = GetDefaultAudioEndpoint();

    if (device != null)
        progressBar1.Value = (int)(Math.Round(device.AudioMeterInformation.MasterPeakValue * 100));
    else
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
}

public MMDevice GetDefaultAudioEndpoint()
{
    MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
    return enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);
}
```